# How to print contents of an array containing a class and how to access certain value of the array in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift

So I have defined the following:

```
 class Passenger {

    let passengerId: Int, firstName: String, lastName: String, daysOnTrip: Int

    init(passengerId: Int, firstName: String, lastName: String, daysOnTrip: Int) {
        self.passengerId = passengerId
        self.firstName = firstName
        self.lastName = lastName
        self.daysOnTrip = daysOnTrip
    }

}

let peopleTravelling = [
    Passenger(passengerId:1, firstName:"John", lastName:"Doe", daysOnTrip: 10),
    Passenger(passengerId:2, firstName:"Sara", lastName:"Johns", daysOnTrip: 5)
]
```

1) How can I print the contents of "peopleTravelling" in a vertical list?

*e.g.*

*John Doe traveling for 10 days*

*Sara Johns traveling for 5 days*

2) How can I access the "passengerId" and "daysOnTrip" values so that I can use them in further app logic and calculations?

Comment: `for people in peopleTravelling {
    print("\(people.firstName) \(people.lastName) traveling for \(people.daysOnTrip) day" + (people.daysOnTrip > 1 ? "s":""))
}`

Comment: You can also use just one line of code for that: 
`peopleTravelling.forEach({print("\($0.firstName) \($0.firstName) traveling for \($0.daysOnTrip) days")})
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this code lines

1)

```
for people in peopleTravelling
{
    print("\(people.firstName) \(people.lastName) traveling for \(people.daysOnTrip) days")
}
```

2)

depends that you want to do, for example all days of trip

```
var daysTravel = 0
for people in peopleTravelling
{
   daysTravel += people.daysOnTrip
}
```

access specific item

```
print(peopleTravelling[0].daysOnTrip)
```

Comment: So basically I am trying to calculate in a 10-day trip defined by a "tripDuration" value, how many passengers there are in any given day based on "daysOnTrip" since not all passengers would spend an equal amount of time on the trip. So for example on day 3 there are 2 passengers where on day 7 there is only 1 passenger since the second passenger has spent only 5 days on the trip.